# Mysql date search between 2 dates returns 0 rows

Tags: php, mysql

Basically i want to get the people who checked in after given date and checked out before or on the same day of the check out date. Here are some queries i have tried.

```
SELECT * FROM `booking`
        WHERE (check_in BETWEEN '2017-09-10' AND '2017-09-21')
          AND (check_out between '2017-09-10' and '2017-09-21')
```

which returns 0 rows
and

```
SELECT * FROM `booking`
        WHERE check_in >= '2017-09-10' AND check_out <= '2017-09-21'
```

returns 0 rows. I have a customer check in on 2017-09-18 and check out on 2017-09-21. How to resolve this ?

Comment: your data stored with time  or only date?

Comment: Provide some sample data set to produce this issue

Comment: are your check_in and check_out fields datetime or varchar? With varchar it will never work properly. Also cast your date strings to date objects first before comparing.

Comment: Have you paid attention to what the MySQL manual for BETWEEN says about comparing date values …?

Comment: @SardorDushamov datetime

Comment: @L.Moharana try to use where DATE(check_in)>='2017-09-10'

Comment: @mohamadmohamad neat trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `booking`
        WHERE DATE(check_in) >= '2017-09-10' AND DATE(check_out) <= '2017-09-21'
```

Comment: @l-moharana did you try?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the values in your DB but a common mistake that you may have made is assume that your database 2017-09-21 entry will fit into `(check_out between '2017-09-10' and '2017-09-21')`. Your 2017-09-21 is in fact 2017-09-21 00:00:00. Most probably your database date has some non-zero hours and minutes to it which makes it LARGER than 2017-09-21 00:00:00.

For e.g. 2017-09-21 05:06:23 is larger than 2017-09-21 00:00:00 and will not fit into your condition.

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM `booking`
        WHERE (check_in >= '2017-09-10' AND check_in < '2017-09-22')
          AND (check_out >= '2017-09-10' AND check_out <'2017-09-22')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql date format function in check in and check out field

```
SELECT * FROM `booking`
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(check_in,'%Y-%m-%d') >= '2017-09-10' AND 
DATE_FORMAT(check_out,'%Y-%m-%d') <= '2017-09-21'
```